# Joomla! Community Builder extension for tracking users' total logged-in time

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

Thanks for taking time out of your busy day to read my post.

My client requires that I track the total amount of time a user is logged-in to our Community Builder Joomla site. I am looking for an out-of-the-box solution, so I don't have to reinvent the wheel. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specifically for community builder however it does keep tracks of all the registered users who have logged in, their IP address, number of times they have logged in, from which countries and cities and other bits n bobs for Joomla 1.5 and 2.5.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/visitors/8946

Hope this helps you. 
Regards